# How to Reload UICollectionView Supplementary View (HeaderView)

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, reload, uicollectionreusableview

First things first:

> 1. I do NOT Want to reload whole CollectionView.
> 2. I also do NOT want to reload the section either (since it is same as reloadData because my cv only has 1 section).

I put some controls in the Supplementary View since this view acts as a header view. On some case, I want to hide/show the controls as needed. In order to do that I need to reload the Supplementary View as the data for it is already updated.

What I have tried:

```
UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext *layoutContext =
[[UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext alloc] init];
[layoutContext invalidateSupplementaryElementsOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                        atIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]];
[[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] invalidateLayoutWithContext:layoutContext];
```

This crash of course. The code doesn't look right either but I am not sure how to construct the UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext properly and telling the collectionview to reload just the Supplementary View.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you need only to update the header view of a particular section, then you can do something similar to this:

```
if let header = collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: indexPath.section)) as? MyCollectionHeaderView {
    // Do your stuff here
    header.myLabel.isHidden = true // or whatever
}
```

Code fragment `IndexPath(item: 0, section: indexPath.section)` may seem a bit weird, but it turns out that the `supplementaryView` is only returned on the first item in the section.

Comment: Weird how you're forced to refactor out all setup code from the data source methods when you want to do this.

Comment: After searching for the answer for over 2 days this is the one that finally works for Swift 5 on Xcode 11.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how you have grouped the cells of the collection view.

The simplest solution would be to reload the particular cell using:

```
- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths
```

Comment: This only reload the normal cell. I want to reload the supplementaryview. Sorry i edited my question to indicate supplementaryview

Comment: In that case maybe you can iterate over all subviews in your uicollectionview and setNeedsDisplay only on the headerView. You can use the tag property to identify the headerView

Comment: setNeedsdisplay does not reload the view. it just refreshes it.

Comment: setNeedsDisplay calls for drawRect: method. It redraws the components again.

Comment: Yes it redraw the component based on the data called by viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind the first time. Thus, remains the same. And so does not do what I want.